# Animate Logo just like Skype iPad App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am building a application I need to animate logo just like skype application. I am still not sure how to get the affect skype logo appear while starting the application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as my understanding on your question, you can try using frame images (frames of gif images to be precise )on `UIImageView`.

```
 NSArray * imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], nil]; //this will be the frames of animation images in sequence.
 ringImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,200,600,600)];
 ringImage.animationImages = imageArray;
 ringImage.animationDuration = 1.5;//this the animating speed which you can modify
 ringImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
 [ringImage startAnimating];//this method actually does the work of animating your frames.
```

**To STOP the animation, just use `[ringImage stopAnimating];`**

Do let me know if this answers your question:)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just find out this example using MCSpriteLayer...
You can go through [this link](http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/)...
Also they have downloadable [link Here](http://mysterycoconut.com/examplecode/CoreCastlevania.zip)

This solved my purpose hope this will help you guys too